# Micronaut: Implement custom Info endpoint element

Tags: micronaut

I'm trying to implement a custom element to get published by [Micronaut's Info Endpoint](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#infoEndpoint), but no custom data appear when querying `/info`. Using Micronaut version 2.4.0.

Here is my code so far:

- `application.yml`

```
[...]
endpoints:
  info:
    enabled: true
    sensitive: false
    git:
      enabled: true
[...]
```

- `build.gradle`

```
dependencies {
  [...]
  implementation('io.micronaut:micronaut-management')
  [...]
}
```

- `RegisteredUsersInfo`

```
import io.micronaut.context.env.MapPropertySource;
import io.micronaut.context.env.PropertySource;
import io.micronaut.management.endpoint.info.InfoSource;
import io.micronaut.runtime.context.scope.Refreshable;
import org.reactivestreams.Publisher;

import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Set;

import static io.reactivex.Flowable.just;

//@Singleton  // No success even with this annotation set
public class RegisteredUsersInfo implements InfoSource {

  // Business component to receive data from:
  private final SubjectMetadataDataSource subjectMetadataDataSource;

  public RegisteredUsersInfo(final SubjectMetadataDataSource subjectMetadataDataSource) {
    this.subjectMetadataDataSource = subjectMetadataDataSource;
  }

  @Override
  public Publisher<PropertySource> getSource() {
    return just(getUserPropertySource());
  }

  private PropertySource getUserPropertySource() {
    final Map<String, Set<String>> userProperties = 
           Map.of("knownID", subjectMetadataDataSource.listOfKnownUserIDs());
    return new MapPropertySource("user", userProperties);
  }

}
```

I can't see what's missing/wrong with this. Any help appreciated.

Background info: Mentioned [Git Info Source](https://docs.micronaut.io/latest/guide/index.html#infoEndpoint) works as expected.

Thanks

Christian

Answer (score 1):

OK, making this slight change in method `getUserPropertySource()`:

```
    [...]
    final Map<String, Set<String>> userProperties = 
          Map.of("knownID", Set.of("foo", "bar", "baz"));
    [...]
```

gives me the following response when querying `/info`:

```
{
  "known-id": [
    "foo",
    "baz",
    "bar"
  ],
  [...]
}
```

So reason for my "problem" was the fact that `subjectMetadataDataSource.listOfKnownUserIDs()` returns an empty `Set`!

Application of

```
    [...]
    final Map<String, Set<String>> userProperties = 
          Map.of("knownID", Set.of());
    [...]
```

reproduces disappearance of expected additional JSON elements from `/info` response.

I would expect to get an empty JSON array with empty input like so:

```
{
  "known-id": [],
  [...]
}
```